# C++ split string to vector<string>

Tags: c++

The function I am using is

```
vector<string> tokenise(string s){

}
```

Firstly, I intend to split the string into substrings, in which case the string is always arithmetic expression (e.g. "100+5") and there could be some whitespaces.

"100+5" is needed to convert to "100", "+", "5"

After conversion, the substrings will be stored in a vector and return it. I am struggling with the fist step and using the subscript to loop over a string. The type of the value returned is char, so there is no way to put it in the vector.

Comment: You can convert a `char` to a string using `std::string str(1, ch);`

Comment: If you only use strings with one character, you may as well use `char`

Comment: @InternetAussie As I asked, I have to use strings, which leaves me no options.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Can you explain further in actual code?

Comment: If that's the case, why not return `std::vector<char>`?

Comment: @Galik return "100" ,"+" ,"5"

Comment: I vote against closing the question as "unclear what you're asking" — clearly it has been sufficiently clear to at least three users, one of whom has understood it clearly enough to give an answer acceptable to the OP>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<string> tokenise(string s)
{
    vector<string> v;

    string number;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        if((s[i] >= '0') && (s[i] <= '9'))
        {
            number += string(1, s[i]);
        }
        else if(s[i] == '.')
        {
            number += string(1, s[i]);
        }
        else if((s[i] == '+') || (s[i] == '-') || (s[i] == '*') || (s[i] == '/'))
        {
            if(number.size())
            {
                v.push_back(number);
                number.clear();
            }
            v.push_back(string(1, c));
        }
    }

    if(number.size())
    {
        v.push_back(number);
        number.clear();
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, almost the same as my idea

Answer (score 2):

You could just call the string's `substring` method, after figuring out the range of characters that are either digits, arithmetic characters, or unwanted.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, coz the range of string to distinguish digits and operators is uncertain.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned - *The type of the value returned is char, so there is no way to put it in the vector.*

You have some function that returns a character. You want to then insert the equivalent string into the vector.

Assuming your vector is defined as

```
std::vector<std::string> broken_strings;
```

So you can do it as follows.

```
char ch = ...; // Here comes the character that you get from the function.
std::string str(1, ch);
broken_strings.push_back(str);
```

Then you can return broken_strings.

Edit:

OP mentions that he wants to tokenize algebraic expressions.
So it will have to be done it a different way.

Following is a simple approach.

```
 std::vector<std::string> broken;
 std::string temp;
 for ( int i = 0; i<s.length() ;i++){
     char ch = s[i];
     if (ch == ' ')
         continue;
     else if (ch >= '0' && ch <='9')
         temp += ch;
     else{
         if (temp.length() != 0)
             broken.push_back(temp);
         temp = "";
         temp += ch;
         broken.push_back(temp);
         temp = "";
     }
 } 
 if (temp.length() != 0)
     broken.push_back(token);
 return broken;
```

You can see the demo of the same here

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/ePYxNI)

Comment: That, or with `string::substr`

Comment: You have completely changed your question. Now you need some logic to identify where a token ends. You might want to look at lexing tools like lex or flex.

Comment: sorry for that, is there any easy method to solve this.

Comment: Assuming you have set of characters that can be the operators, it can be done. I will edit my answer to do the same.

Comment: Where do you declare the "s"

Comment: @JoeyLU `s` is your function parameter. I picked it from your question.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I really appreciate that